Can not change map unit while trying to use unknown spatial reference
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2. Whenever I add a new map to my project, the spatial reference of the map is set to Web Mercator by default [which should be none]. I want to set the map coordinate system to Unknown and use Inch as map unit but there seems to no way to do that. The help page of ESRI is not helping, the map unit drop-down in the general section of the map properties is always muted. I tried to import a mxd with unknown spatial reference that solves the problem of setting map coordinate system to unknown but I can't set the map unit to Inch. So, is there any way to set map unit to Inch while using Unknown Spatial Reference?

The default projection is that of the first data layer, which are 3857 web services. If you create a nominal map, and save it, then you can use that to create a new map.

Regarding your issue about not being able to set map units when a map has no spatial reference or an unknown spatial reference, I am quite sure Esri will state that is "by design."  The map units cannot be set when ArcGIS Pro has no idea the units of the map itself.  How can ArcGIS Pro convert the data's units of measure to a different unit of measure when the map's spatial reference is unknown?
